# How to compare a list in python with another list and replace it with Nan?

Tags: python, pandas, list

```
delta_list = ['2','3','4',nan]
lb = ['1','2','3','4']
ub = ['5','6','7','8']
```

condition:

```
flag_1 = [np.where((np.array(delta_list) > np.array(lb)) & (np.array(delta_list) < np.array(ub)),0,1)]
```

here: if `nan` is being compared with any value it is `returning 1` (obvious) but I want it to be like if the `comparison is with nan` in the `delta_list` , it should always `return nan` **instead** of the `flag_1 condition`.
How do I achieve this?
Should I make a new list and compare the index with delta_list and replace that index value with nan?
Please help!!

Expected Output : `flag_1 = ['1','1','1','1']`
Desired Output  : `flag_1 =['1','1','1',nan]`

`nan` because `delta_list 4th element is nan` and hence

```
[np.where((np.array(delta_list) > np.array(lb)) & (np.array(delta_list) < np.array(ub)),0,1)]
```

should **NOT BE** evaluated at all if nan is encountered in delta_list and it should simply `return nan` in my `flag_1` list

Comment: Can you provide an example of your expected output? Your explanation isn't making sense to me.

Comment: Hey I just added. can you check?

Comment: [mre] - this gives me only a NameError on nan. What are you trying to achieve? Instead of explaining in text - show inputs, show the wanted output and explain for a single value why this output is what should come out of it. jeszrale seems to have gottet behind what you want - but I simply don't

Comment: thank you, I did that. Can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

If numbers are less like `10` is possible compare strings, so use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with new condition for compare by `NaN`s:

```
delta_list = ['2','3','4',np.nan]
lb = ['1','2','3','4']
ub = ['5','6','7','8']

m1 = (np.array(delta_list) > np.array(lb)) & (np.array(delta_list) < np.array(ub))
m2 = pd.isna(delta_list)

flag_1 = np.select([m2, m1], [np.nan, '1'], default='0')
print (flag_1)
['1' '1' '1' 'nan']
```

If need avoid string `nan` is possible use `None`:

```
flag_1 = np.select([m2, m1], [None, '1'], default='0')
print (flag_1)
['1' '1' '1' None]
```

Comment: key error as 0 is coming as an error